# C# run code every 30 days

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I were to run some code, perhaps send an email, every 30 days to users of my site, how would that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which framework are you working with? I have some pointers if you're developing with .Net 4.0 like I am.

If you have access to your machine where you can install services I would utilize the new and improved Workflow Service for this situation. What's nice about them is that Workflows can persists for minutes, hours, days, weeks, months, etc. lying "dormant" until delays time periods finish.

If it's an IIS machine (and if that's the route you would like to take) it is relatively simple to build it straight as a "Workflow Service" project/solution in VS 2010. From there you are presented with a designer and several workflow activities in the toolbar.

Add a flowchart activity to place your email activities inside of. Flowchart is ideal because it can initialize whatever you need to and decision flow can redirect backwards  in direction (as opposed to the always forward moving sequence activity). What you need to do with your logic is up to you from there since your question doesn't provide a lot of details.

Now if you're using .Net 3.5 then I would think about refraining from building Workflows since you have to migrate when switching to 4.0 (WF 3.5 is NOT compatible with 4.0). With admin access to the machine you can install a Windows Service that contains a timer to fire code every 30 days (or however defined) as needed.

Comment: @Soeren, the key here is that you cannot reliably trigger the event from the asp.net worker process/IIS. You need the windows service.

Answer (score 19):

Use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614(VS.85).aspx) to run your application.

Answer (score 4):

Options:

1) Console app that runs in Windows Task Scheduler

2) Windows Service
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/window_service11262005045007AM/window_service.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If it's SQL Server specific, you can use [SQL Jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with your ASP.NET app instead of a separate app, you have some options:

Since you want it to run every 30 days instead of daily, I recommend this method of using a schedule table instead of application variables or cache to schedule jobs:

You can setup a schedule table in your db and check when it was last updated in your global.asax.  On the Session start, check if the current date is more than 30 days. If it is, then call a method to send out emails.

If you send out emails, then update your schedule table with the current date.